# Eclipse で javadoc のエラーを検出する方法

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse で javadoc を書いていると、引数名が間違っている等のエラーに気づきにくく困っています。
javadoc のエラーを eclipse で自動で検出する設定か、該当のことができる eclipse 用のプラグインなどはありますでしょうか?

Comment: eclipseとjavadocのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

環境設定→Java→Compiler→Javadoc

- Process Javadoc Comment を有効に
- Malformed Javadoc comments を Warnning 以上に
- Validate tag arguments を有効に

これで Javadoc 内で引数名が誤って記述されている場合 Eclipse 上で確認できるようになると思います。これ以外の設定には、Javadoc のチェックをどの範囲で有効にするかなどがあります。

Comment: あ、まさにそれですね!ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 3):

Checkstyle pluginで出来ませんでしたっけ?

Comment: あー。checkstyle は考えてなかったですが、checkstyle だと、syntax 以外にももっと細かいところまでチェックできそうですね。
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html